# Define S3 Group generics for incompatible classes

Tags: r, class, generics, r-s3

Say, I am implementing a custom S3 class, called "myclass":

```
myvec <- 1:5
class(myvec) <- "myclass"
```

I define Group Ops generics so that the class is preserved after standard operations.

```
Ops.myclass <- function(e1, e2) {
  if(is(e1, "myclass")) {
    e1 <- unclass(e1)
    structure(NextMethod(), class="myclass")
  } else if(is(e2, "myclass")) {
    e2 <- unclass(e2)
    structure(NextMethod(), class="myclass")
  }
}
```

Now my class is preserved with, for example, addition:

```
1 + myvec  # still has myclass
myvec + 1  # still has myclass
```

However, when I do this for objects that have their own Group generics, I get into issues:

```
myvec + Sys.Date()
[1] 19454 19455 19456 19457 19458
attr(,"class")
[1] "myclass"
Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("Ops.myclass", "+.Date") for "+"
```

Not only does it produce a warning, but in addition the result is different:

```
unclass(myvec) + Sys.Date()
[1] "2023-04-07" "2023-04-08" "2023-04-09" "2023-04-10" "2023-04-11"
```

**Question**: How can I resolve this warning and make this operation return the same result it would return if `myvec` didn't have a class?

Basically I want `myclass` to have it's own Group Generics, but act subserviently in case of a conflict and give priority to the other class, when in collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, you are out of luck with R < 4.3.0.  I was going to suggest defining S4 methods like:

```r
setOldClass("zzz")
setMethod("Ops", c("zzz", "zzz"), function(e1, e2) <do stuff>)
setMethod("Ops", c("zzz", "ANY"), function(e1, e2) <do stuff>)
setMethod("Ops", c("ANY", "zzz"), function(e1, e2) <do stuff>)
```

because S4 generic functions perform S4 dispatch before S3 dispatch (if they are also S3 generic).  Then, in theory, S3 dispatch ambiguities would never be detected.

But then I remembered that all members of the `Ops` group are internally generic and so do not dispatch S4 methods when neither argument is an S4 object, as in the `<zzz> + <Date>` case.

R 4.3.0 introduces a new generic function `chooseOpsMethod` to allow users to specify how S3 dispatch ambiguities should be resolved for members of the `Ops` group.  It is documented in [`?Ops`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/groupGeneric.html) and of course in [`?chooseOpsMethod`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chooseOpsMethod.html).  I will assume that you have read the relevant sections and just suggest this:

```r
.S3method("chooseOpsMethod", "zzz", 
          function(x, y, mx, my, cl, reverse) TRUE)
.S3method("Ops", "zzz",
          function(e1, e2) {
              if (inherits(e1, "zzz")) {
                  class(e1) <- NULL
                  cl <- oldClass(e2)
              } else {
                  class(e2) <- NULL
                  cl <- oldClass(e1)
              }
              r <- callGeneric(e1, e2)
              ## Do not assign a class to 'r' if the "other" argument inherits
              ## from a class with a method for this generic function ...
              if (is.null(cl) ||
                  (all(match(paste0(   "Ops", ".", cl), .S3methods(   "Ops"), 0L) == 0L) && 
                   all(match(paste0(.Generic, ".", cl), .S3methods(.Generic), 0L) == 0L)))
                  class(r) <- "zzz"
              r
          })
```

```r
x <- structure(0:5, class = "zzz")
x + x
## [1]  0  2  4  6  8 10
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "zzz"
x + 0
## [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "zzz"
0 + x
## [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "zzz"
x + .Date(0L)
## [1] "1970-01-01" "1970-01-02" "1970-01-03" "1970-01-04" "1970-01-05" "1970-01-06"
.Date(0L) + x
## [1] "1970-01-01" "1970-01-02" "1970-01-03" "1970-01-04" "1970-01-05" "1970-01-06"
```

That works only because there is no `chooseOpsMethod.Date` and because `chooseOpsMethod.default` returns `FALSE` unconditionally.  Someone else could come along and register a `chooseOpsMethod.Date` returning `TRUE`, spoiling the behaviour of `<Date> + <zzz>`, but that is the risk you take by relying on S3 instead of S4 ...